# compute the measure $ \large \ m_{*} (\mathbb{Q}^d \cap [0,1]^d) \ $

Tags: lebesgue-measure

Let $ \ m_{*} \ $ be the Lebesgue Exterior measure on $ \ \mathbb{R}^{d} \ $ , where $ \ \mathbb{R}^{d} \ $ is the countable product of $ \ \mathbb{R} \ $.

Then compute

(i) $ \large \ m_{*} (\mathbb{Q}^d \cap [0,1]^d) \ $

**Answer:**

If $ \ d \ $ be finite , then $ Q^d \cap [0,1]^d \ $ will be countable and hence $ \ m_* (Q^d \cap [0,1]^d  )=0 $

But if $ \ d \ $ be countably infinite , then $ \ Q^d \ $ may be uncountable and in that case I can't proceed in above way.

**Help me out**